# wp-admin and wp-login.php - 404 error for those who do not administrator (wordpress + htaccess)

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, hide, http-status-code-404

I try to hide the traces as wordpress on my website for security reasons. Does anyone know how to create a rule using htaccess, according to which a third party user (with a different ip) redirected to on /404.php if he visits the wp-admin and wp-login.php ... I've seen third-party plug-ins (?) To address this problem, but I do not want to create an extra load on the CMS.

Comment: Security by obscurity....what's the point? It's obvious which blogs use wordpress even without navigating to wp-admin or wp-login

Answer (score 1):

you can use simple redirect in .htaccess like this

```
Redirect 301/wp-admin/ http://www.yourwebsite.com/404.php
```

But if you're trying to completely hide wordpress it requires a little bit of technical work...what I did in mine, is search every files in the wp-include and wp-content folder as well as the root folder that contained the wp-login.php and /wp-admin/*somefolder* words, and change everything to a file or folder to a name of your choice that no-one can guess. Although you have to be very careful as not to change an important code there...